# What is the physical significance of the area and shape of hysteresis curve of ferromagnetic materials?

Tags: electromagnetism

Why do some materials have thinner/broader hysteresis curves than others and what does this difference in shape imply in terms of magnetic properties of the substances? Is there any significance to the area under the hysteresis curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, the broader a material's hysteresis curve is, the more permanent its magnetization is.

The area inside the hysteresis loop is the energy dissipated in the material per cycle.  See this previous question:  [Computing energy loss for a hysteresis curve](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/170408/computing-energy-loss-for-a-hysteresis-curve?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The area measures the amount of energy lost  per cycle of magnetization.
The area of hysteresis curve for steel is more than that of soft iron.The magnetic materials whose B-H curve is more is useful for making permanent magnets.Connectivity as well as retentivity is high.